# Minminum value in a map haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary

I have a question about how to retrieve the minimum value of a `Map`.

I have a `Map k (Maybe a,Maybe b)` and I need to retrieve the key with the smallest value on the first element of the tuple (the smallest `a` ), but I couldn't find any predefined function. Is there some function I can use or I should implement that by myself?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need the constraint `Ord a`. Also, you need to decide how to compare `Just x` and `Nothing` (because you'll have to compare `(Just x, y)` with `(Nothing, z)`). I'll assume you want `Just x` to be smaller than `Nothing` for all `x`. If you use `toList` to covert the map to a list, you can then use `minimumBy` on the list with a custom comparison function. Moreover, the second part of the tuple (`Maybe b`) is irrelevant, so we'll just call consider `Map k (Maybe a, b)` and get a more general function.

I suggest something like

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.List

minimum' :: (Ord a) => M.Map k (Maybe a, b) -> k
minimum' = fst . (minimumBy comp) . M.toList
    where
      comp (_, (Nothing, _)) (_, (Just _, _)) = GT
      comp (_, (Just _, _)) (_, (Nothing, _)) = LT
      comp (_, (Nothing, _)) (_, (Nothing, _)) = EQ
      comp (_, (Just x, _)) (_, (Just y, _)) = compare x y
```

It's hard to tell what kind of behavior you actually want with regards to the `Nothing`s, but another, more reasonable(*), alternative would be for the minimum function to have return type `Maybe k`, with `Nothing` returned in case the smallest element found (as above) is `(Nothing, _)`. One way to achieve this is to first `filter` the list returned by `toList` to eliminate all elements whose values are `(Nothing, _)`.

(*) Letting `Just x` be smaller than `Nothing` is kinda bad. You'll want the *opposite* behavior when looking for the largest element, so it all gets rather inconsistent and ugly. In other words, when the type `a` is ordered, the type `Maybe a` is only *partially* ordered (in a natural way -- of course you can force a total order, as above).

Comment: Another thing you might want to consider is what to do if the first elements of the tuple are equal. In that case, you might want to use the second element as a tie-breaker.

Comment: Indeed, but that would introduce an `Ord b` constraint, and it's not clear-cut that one wants that behavior. But is definitely a point to consider.

Comment: @isturdy: I think when mhwombat said "the first element of the tuple", he meant the first element of the *value* tuple, not the key in the key-value-tuple.

Comment: Thanks,
it was similar to what I did, but your version is more "hasklish".